# ReactJS + ServerSide with ExpressJS - need a way to dictate what to load on the server vs client

Tags: reactjs, react-router, server-side-rendering, react-server

So I'm working on POC app, that needs to have SEO optimized content(=== rendered on the server). But within the same route there might be a dynamic data coming from different sources and it might take a while to capture all that data. This dynamic data is not needed for SEO so async load is going to be implemented.

What I have so far is something look like this (bear in mind this is just sample ):

```
// routes.js
import serverRender from './services/aboutService';

const routes = (
  <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
    <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/about">
      <Route
        path="/About"
        component={AboutContainer}
        serverRender={serverRender} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
);

// aboutService.js
const serverRender = () => {
    return axios.get("http://localhost:3002/services/about")
      .then(res => res.data)
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
}
export default serverRender;

// AboutContainer.js
import React from 'react';

export default class About extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: { username: "", isFetching : true, hasError: false }
    };

    this._fetchNonSEOData = this.fetchNonSEOData.bind(this);
    console.log("CompetitionContainer constructor: ", props)
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    //this._fetchNonSEOData();
  }

  _fetchNonSEOData(){
    // dynamic content, not important for Crawlers
    // will call setState here to update state properties
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>User: {this.props.data.username}</h1>
        <div className="non-seo">
          {this._fetchNonSEOData()}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

server.js which is using ExpressJS (tiny slice of it):

// server.js
    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      ReactRouter.match({ routes, location: req.url }, (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {

```
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send(err.message);
    }

    if (redirectLocation) {
      return res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
    }

    let markup;
    if (renderProps) {
      preRenderMiddleware(renderProps)
        .then(data => {

          const appElement = (
            <ReactRouter.RouterContext
              {...renderProps}
              createElement={(Component, props) => {
                                return <Component data={data} {...props} />;
                            }}
            />
          );
          //
          let markup = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(appElement);
          console.log("AppString:", markup)

          return res.render('index', { markup, head });
        })
    } else {
      // otherwise we can render a 404 page
      markup = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<NotFoundPage/>);
      res.status(404);
    }
  });
});
```

So as you see there is preRenderMiddleware which returns resolved Promise and this is the part I think I might have wrong:

```
//preRenderMiddleware.js
const defaultServerRender = () => Promise.resolve();

function preRenderMiddleware({ routes, location, params }) {
  const matchedRoute = routes[routes.length - 1];
  const serverRenderHandler = matchedRoute.serverRender || defaultServerRender;
  return serverRenderHandler(params);
}
```

So my problem is that getting expected markup from the server - in AboutContainer this.props.data is getting data. But then, when client side kicks in, this.props.data is undefined.

Anyone could point me to some good solution? I'm sure I'm not the first person with this problem. 
I came across some solutions for this but all of the re-requested same data on the client which is what I would hope to avoid and it would be a bit bizzare same thing again.

Also I don't want to use Redux / any Flux for it.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have the data props on your server-side not client-side. you should pass it to the client side.
I suggest you try below solution:

On server-side, in your example "AboutContainer" component, write the props in a hidden div element and read it on your client-side:

```
var canUseDOM = !!(
  (typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
  window.document && window.document.createElement)
);
export default class About extends Component {
  render(){
    initData(){
      if(!canUseDOM)return <div hidden id="propsData">{this.props.data}</div>
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>User: {this.props.data.username}</h1>
        <div className="non-seo">
          {this._fetchNonSEOData()}
        </div>
        {initData()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And now on your client-side:

```
const data  = document.getElementById("namee").innerHTML
```

I hope it helps.